# How would you insure yourself against the whole world forgetting you?

Tags: internal-consistency, society

You are a multimillionaire and head of a corporation enjoying worldwide success. You have everything one could dream of: a nice car, a big mansion, lots and lots of money, a beautiful wife and kids, and a business that only gets better.

However, a wizard, having a very bad case of the "mondays", put a very nasty curse on you after you stole his parking space: in about one month, the whole world will *completely* forget about you. You have no doubt that the curse is real: in about a month, you will lose everything you have achieved in life. Nobody will believe you're the one in charge of your own company, your own wife won't recognize you and your bank account is inaccessible to you.

Even though all traces of your very existence have been erased from everyone's minds AND everything written/recorded as if you've never existed, everything you achieved is still there. It doesn't disappear, it will simply have no owner: your corporation will suddenly have no leader and nobody will know what happened, your wife will wonder why the hell she has a wedding ring on her finger and where all those brats calling her "mom" came from, and the bank account with millions of precious dollars will have the owner's name wiped, leaving bankers dumbfounded.

You accept defeat and try to form a plan to keep as much of your wealth in your "new" life as humanly possible. You want to transfer most of your money from the old *known* "you" to the new *unknown* "you" one month in the future, so you can run off somewhere and enjoy a new life in the bahamas or something (you never really cared about your wife and kids that much anyway).

Given how the curse completely wipes your existence (*again, from everyone's minds and written/recorded stuff, not your literal existence*), how would you transfer your money and ownership of the company and everything else materialistic to the new you? If you can't transfer ownership, can you liquidate it in such a short time? How will the world treat someone like you, who suddenly started existing out of nowhere and had loads of cash?

Comment: The curse didn't completely wipe your existence if you still exist.

Comment: @Frostfyre Always that _one guy_. Changed it so it's even more clear on what I _really_ meant.

Comment: Just go rob a bunch of banks and then buy back your company after with the money.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. You mean, rob the banks shortly *before* everyone forgets about you? That's genius! Unfortunately, you couldn't really make enough to buy a successful business that way; bank robbers usually only get a few thousand dollars.

Comment: @KSmarts I guess you can just transfer all your company assets into bitcoins and keep the wallet on a personal hard drive and then you'd keep all the money after too.

Comment: "How will the world treat someone like you, who suddenly started existing out of nowhere and had loads of cash?" [Well...](https://xkcd.com/1400/)

Comment: How would the curse impact aliases established before the deadline?

Comment: This question is about how to get our of a scenario not about worldbuilding. It is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: "You have everything one could dream of..." Your dreams are super small...

Comment: Did you just curse someone with a fresh start?

Comment: Contact every newspaper, TV station and Internet advertisement provider in the world which will send regularly the following message: "Dear sir, I very deeply regret the incident where I stole your parking space. Please, pleeeaaase accept my *utmost regrets* and I am very, very, *very* sorry about my inexcusable behavior."

Comment: @sphennings I honestly don't understand the logic of some of the members here. If my question is off-topic because it's about a scenario instead of worldbuilding, then why is this [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/89061/how-to-poison-a-creature-that-measures-more-than-a-dozen-meters)?

Comment: "Can I poison a dragon?" and "What poison could work on a dragon?" are both questions needed to flesh out a world. You have created a scenario and asked us to tell you the story of how your character would get out of it. For more information I suggest reading [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened).

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to turn the curse to your advantage. you just have to use a little creative preparation to rise, phoenixlike, from the ashes.

First, get a hold of as many [Bearer Bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearer_bond)as you can.  They don't have to be US bearer bonds, just the equivalent of whatever country you think you might be landing in.

The idea here is to get as much money tied up in things that require the physical document, but that document is not tied to some sort of recorded identity.  Bearer bonds are the first thing I thought of.  Cash is the next, since it is a bearer bond, after a fashion.

Cash, while unwieldy, has another advantage here.  You can make the curse work for you.  If you start pulling large amounts of cash out, the financial institutions will report this to the government. They are going to be telling the IRS your name and so on, but you don't care because the curse is going to erase you from their systems and paperwork before they can get their acts together to go arrest you.

If I am not mistaken, The old deed system for real estate used to be tied to the document, not to the name.  Find a country that still has this practice, buy a place, beef up security, and stash your cash and such.

The curse hits, you have a ton of cash.  a lot of cash can buy a pretty solid identity, especially in some country with non digital record keeping.

Finally, before the curse hits, set your company up to fail, badly.  Maybe take out a ton of debt for some fanciful and doomed to fail projects.  Promote some idiots into the C-suite.  When your curse hits, no one will know about you, not even your board of directors.  When the company starts to slide, either buy a ton of shares and then [short the stock](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shortselling.asp), making a bunch of money as it founders and incidentally laundering a bunch of money in the process.  Or you could wait till it bombs badly enough for you to start a hostile takeover, install yourself as CEO, and keep going.  There are more than one way to do this.  Since you know the company, you might be able to demonstrate to the board what shrewd measures you could take to get the  company righted again and get brought in to "rescue" it, firing the idiots you put in the C-suite before they do much damage.

This might work better for a story set 30 years ago, but it still sounds fun

Answer (score 2):

Since even becoming like Odysseus and winning immortal renown isn't going to work, you will need to liquidate whatever is possible and transfer it to a safe place before the erasure takes place.

One problem is that during the month you have left, anything you do could come under scrutiny and be thwarted, while after the month, you plan requires that you have whatever tokens of identity are needed to recover whatever you are seeking to recover. In the first instance, moving large amounts of stock or money, or purchasing bearer bonds or gold bars is likely to raise a few eyebrows, if not the attention of the local governing authorities and police. In the second instance, assuming you have managed to deliver a ton of gold bullion, pallet loads of cash or bonds to a secure warehouse, you have the issues of accessing it and movie it out.

You don't have an identity, so renting a car/truck/forklift is going to be difficult. Even getting around normally is going to be an issue, about the only way to go from point a to b initially will be public transit (so long as you have tickets or change in your pocket), and all transactions will be in cash, until you have some sort of identity created or activated. The only true way for this to work is to be able to create an identity on the month prior to the event happening, and being able to set yourself up in the days just prior to being "erased" (i.e. buy a car, rent an apartment etc.)

The other "out" is to establish a new identity but walk away from everything in the past. You had become a millionaire because you have some talent or drive to do so, so go to your newly rented garage on day one of your new life and create a new company. You have the ideas, but more importantly the experience from the first go round, so you should be able to create something new and exciting faster than you did the first time. Maybe immortal renown *can* be yours in your second life.

> This is the story of a man, one who was never at a loss. He had travelled far in the world, after the sack of Troy....

Answer (score 1):

Set up a numbered Swiss bank account. It has no name on the account to be wiped, and you'll still know the number, so you'll still be able to access the account.

Comment: Even numbered accounts have some kind of verification method to prove the account is yours, a code word, token, or some way of saying this account is mine.  In this scenario I would assume those tokens also would disappear making the money inaccessible.

Comment: @JoshKing The scenario says "The bank account with millions of precious dollars will have the owner's name wiped, leaving bankers dumbfounded". It says nothing about other access identifiers. If the question means something other than what it says, it should be edited.

Comment: Yeah, reread the question; I guess if all they forget is your name then the numbered account should work, as you would still possess the verification method.

Answer (score 0):

Would cash and other valuables in a safe deposit box work? If you know the number and have the key, you shouldn't need to prove your identity to get to it. If not, you could just stash valuables in a hiding place.

The real trouble is explaining to the government how a person with no legal identity "suddenly" came to have large amounts of cash.

Comment: Not if that government is the sort of government where such questions can be answered with a bribe...

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that need to be taken care of, and all in a different manners.

1. Liquid assets. Everything that can be turned into cash should be easily protectable. Other people have mentioned bearer bonds, bitcoins - this will all work nicely. Convert as much as you can into those instruments and be safe.
2. Non-liquid assets, like real estate and particularly the company. This will be more difficult. There are ways to convert ownership into a trust, but no trust can remain truly anonymous, an analog of "bearer bonds". You can try, but if there is a legal challenge, you would most likely lose. So basically you can either take big loans against your property and cash out, or transfer ownership to your family and relatives.
3. Personal relationship. This one is the most difficult to salvage. If it's just your wife, you can craft a story that it is her own amnesia, and win her back with confidence. But with kids, relatives and a circle of friends, that would be difficult. Send your family out for a long vacation before the event. Orchestrate a scenario so that they would meet a stranger (you), who would spend time with them and become their best friend before they know it.